# Creating a dynamic menu

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I'd like to make a Drupal 8 menu dynamic so it can i.e. point to the latest node of the articles or news or hide another from the menu if it doesn't have an entry at all.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really have dynamic menus that point to different things. You can write a deriver and so on, but that will be persisted and not updated until you tell it to. You can trigger the necessary updates also without a full cache clear, see how MenuLinkContent does it, but it's still persisted.

Another approach would be to not make the route/output dynamic and not the menu. Point to a custom controller, and there you either dynamically display the latest node (can easily be done with a view, for example) or you redirect to the latest content, to avoid duplicate content.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a deriver, the class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\YOUR_MODULE\Plugin\Derivative;

use Drupal\Component\Plugin\Derivative\DeriverBase;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\Discovery\ContainerDeriverInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


/**
 * Provides menu links.
 */
class MyLinks extends DeriverBase implements ContainerDeriverInterface {

  /**
   * The team storage.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface
   */
  protected $myStorage;


  /**
   * Constructs a XX instance.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface $storage
   *   The storage.
   */
  public function __construct(EntityStorageInterface $storage) {
    $this->myStorage = $storage;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, $base_plugin_id) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('entity.manager')->getStorage('node')
    );
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getDerivativeDefinitions($base_plugin_definition) {
    $links = array();

    $base_plugin_definition = array(
      'enabled' => 1
    ) + $base_plugin_definition;

    // use injected storage !
    $nodes = $this->myStorage->loadMultiple();

    $links['custom_link'] = array (
            'id' =>  'custom_link',
            'title' => t('Click me'),
            'route_name' => 'entity.node.canonical',
            'route_parameters' => array(
              'nid' => 123,
            ),
            'menu_name' => 'main',
            'parent' => 'parent:menu:id',
          ) + $base_plugin_definition;

    return $links;
  }

}
```

Add this class in a custom module in the src/Plugin/Derivative Folder,
and it will be picked up.

> This code only runs during/after cache-rebuild.